# Page control inside of UITableView Header. swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

is it possible to add `page controller` into UITableViewHeader?

[image]

Yellow is table view header, blue is table view.

Below my tableViewHeader: UIView():

```
lazy var resultLabel : UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    return label
}()    
lazy var pageControl = UIPageControl()
    lazy var pageIndex: Int = 0

override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.addSubview(resultLabel)
        configurePageControl()
        setUpConstraints()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setUpConstraints() {
        resultLabel.snp_makeConstraints {
            $0.center.equalTo(snp_center)
        }
        pageControl.snp_makeConstraints {
            $0.top.equalTo(snp_top).offset(20)
            $0.left.equalTo(resultLabel.snp_right).offset(0)
        }
    }

    func configurePageControl() {
        self.pageControl.numberOfPages = 3
        self.pageControl.currentPage = pageIndex
        self.pageControl.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
        self.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        self.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        self.addSubview(pageControl)
    }
```

AND HERE MY VIEW CONTROLLER WHICH WILL HANDLE.

```
class NewsResultsViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    var results: NSArray = NSArray()

    override init(transitionStyle style: UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle, navigationOrientation: UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation, options: [String : AnyObject]?) {
        super.init(transitionStyle: .Scroll, navigationOrientation: .Horizontal, options: options)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        results = ["0:2", "2:1", "0:0"]

        self.dataSource = self

        self.setViewControllers([getViewControllerAtIndex(0)], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        let pageContent: NewsHeaderView = viewController as! NewsHeaderView

        var index = pageContent.pageIndex

        if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound))
        {
            return nil
        }

        index -= 1;

        return getViewControllerAtIndex(index)
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        let pageContent: NewsHeaderView = viewController as! NewsHeaderView

        var index = pageContent.pageIndex

        if (index == NSNotFound)
        {
            return nil;
        }

        index += 1;

        if (index == results.count)
        {
            return nil;
        }


        return getViewControllerAtIndex(index)
    }

    func getViewControllerAtIndex(index: NSInteger) -> NewsTableViewController {
        let getStartedPageContentViewController = NewsHeaderView()

        getStartedPageContentViewController.pageIndex = index
        getStartedPageContentViewController.resultLabel.text = "\(results[index])"

        return getStartedPageContentViewController
    }

}
```

But actually here is some error. I can't go through table view headers (I can go throught view controller). Any helps? Thanks

Comment: If you using storyboard, just put UIPageControl into header view and connect IBOutlets to header. Make also IBOutlet to headerView in your VC and expose methods to change page index.

Comment: Im not using storyboard :\

Answer (score 0):

Just put this function to your code :

```
func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {

    return 3

}

// Enables pagination dots
```

don't forget to set :

```
    dataSource = self

    delegate = self
```